# Not able to parallel test of two cucumber feature file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-grid, cucumber-jvm, parallel-testing

i'm new in cucumber design and i trying to parallel test two feature file(login.feature, registration.feature, both are inside src/test/java/features), but not able run both parallel. can anyone help me out?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 
     4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>NorthernMachine_Automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>4.2.0</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Mandatory -->
                            <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
                            <glue>foo, bar</glue>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                            <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
                            <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                            <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
                            <format>json</format>
                            <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                            <strict>true</strict>
                            <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                            <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                            <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
                            <tags></tags>
                            <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
                            <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
                            <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. -->
                            <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
                            <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
                            <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                            <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
                            <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                            <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                            <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
                            <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
                            <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <!--<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable> -->
                    <!--    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>BuyAGiftFramework.utilities.SendEmailFile</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>cucumber-jvm-parallel</goalPrefix>
                    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>descriptor</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>help-goal</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-html -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Extent Reports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.26-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>0.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my runnerclass, which is inside the src\test\java\runners\MainRunnerTest.java:

```
package runners;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features/"},
    glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
    monochrome = true, tags = {"@RegressionTest"}
)


public class MainRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

MainRunnerTest mainRunnerTest;

@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] features() {
    return mainRunnerTest.features();
}
}
```

Here is my

Comment: Have you had a look at this guide? https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

Comment: cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin is deprecated now. Cucumber 4+ has native support parallel run. I would also recommend you to refer link suggested by @Marit


Alternately you may try this out


```
 import io.cucumber.core.cli.main

public class MyRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.run(new String[]{
        "--threads", "3",
        "-t", "@au and @nz",
        "-g", "com.your.glue",
        "src/test/resources/features/",
      }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
  }
}

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Junit:**

Yes, you can execute features files in parallel in Cucumber. using JUnit and Maven test execution plugins. In fact using JUnit, only the feature files can be executed in parallel not the scenarios with in same file.Maven Surefire can be used to execute the runners.

Add the Surefire plugin configuration to the build section to the POM.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Update your runner class as below:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features/"},
    glue = {"stepDefinitions"},
    monochrome = true, tags = {"@RegressionTest"}
)
```

**TestNG:**

However if you are using TextNG not only you can execute feature files in parallel but scenarios as well inside a feature file.

Add the Maven Surefire plugin configuration to the build section of the POM.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
</plugin>
```

Then update your MainRunnerTest method as below:

```
@Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you solve the issue. cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have update the "maven-surefire-plugin" as you mention and it's work like charm. thanks.

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers :)

Comment: I have both junit and testng runners., when I run `mvn test`, the junit runner runs and how can I change it to run testng runners @rahulrai?